# How to check which millisecond a fault causing a dump happend?

Tags: c++, windows, crash-dumps

I have a core dump that has been generated at a customer site. All I can find from the timestamp is which second the dump-file was opened. (Part of the filename.)

Is it possible to see at which millisecond the exception has occurred?

This would enable me to compare more accurately with the log file (which is in milliseconds).

Comment: I know windbg .time command tells time, but always millisecond 000, which seems unlikely.

Comment: WinDbg uses [GetCurrentProcessUptime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545857(v=vs.85).aspx), which only records with second-level accuracy, so unfortunately I don't think this is possible. Do you really have *that* many events in your log file *every second*?

Comment: Surely it crashed at the point the log file stops?

Comment: @CodyGray maybe they set it to TRACE to work out why it's crashing.

Comment: @OrangeDog The logfile stopped once Windows was finished making the dump-file, this seems to take 1-2 seconds. Long enough that parts of the code had time to log that the realtime-timers were not working properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, ".time" is how you get a dump occurrence timestamp.  For user dumps, it's unlikely - from my observation it's always just second-level accuracy.  For kernel dumps however I have found it's accurate to the millisecond.

However, I've found that the "System Uptime" in ".time" output is accurate to the millisecond for both kernel and user dumps.  In the case that you are able to get the last boot time to millisecond accuracy (for instance by calling "wmic os get lastBootUpTime") you could add the uptime to the lastBootUpTime to get an accurate dump occurrence timestamp.

Comment: Maybe logging the System Uptime would be an idea. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting... I wonder why the kernel dumps would have a higher resolution. They must use a different API to record and retrieve the timestamps.

Comment: Now our log-component writes System Uptime in the beginning of each log. If a dump occurs just look at uptime in the dump and the logs, use a calculator and voilà!